# Bluetooth Low Energy without Services & Characteristics is possible?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, protocols, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm starting to build a connected device (raspberry pi) which is able to share data to an iPhone. It is possible to do that only with sockets and without using Services & Characteristics?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish and what hardware? There are too many unknowns to give an answer.

Comment: I'd like scan devices, send and write data in objective c without ATT, or GATT protocol. just with sockets like TCP sockets with AsyncSocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like get simple bluetooth data with the **RFCOMM** protocol but...

This is NOT possible to use an other protocol than **GATT** unless using the private framework [BluetoothManager](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework).

> This framework can be used to achieve the proposed task, but you won't
>   get your App approved on Appstore, as private API's is not allowed by
>   Apple

source: http://www.pocketmagic.net/bluetooth-and-ios-use-bluetooth-in-your-iphone-apps/

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do that,open an **l2cap** socket; after that  you can use a **write**

and **read** system call but make sure that you are framing it as described in

bluetooth spec(pg 1845 follows commands),for ex **att** **read-req** consists of  opcode

1 octet 0x0a and attribute handle to read occupies 2 octets,  and from read system

call you can analyze **att-read-response** with opcode being 0x0b and rest being

attribute value

Comment: But this isn't available on IOS, isn't it? I find only for OSX https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOBluetooth/Reference/IOBluetoothDevice_reference/index.html